# Opencart call function from module controller

Tags: php, ajax, opencart

I've tried asking this on Opencart forums ([thread link](http://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=86175&p=349196#p349196)), but still can't quite get it, though someone tried to explain this to me. I hope someone here can help.

I've written some extensions before where I have a custom function in the controller called from view , for example:
if I edit admin/controller/sale/customer.php and after index() function add

```
public function foo(){
//code here
}
```

I can access it by using

```
index.php?route=sale/customer/foo
```

Now I have a module in catalog, could I access a function in it's controller from view, in the below example "foo"?

my_module.php:

```
class ControllerModuleMyModule extends Controller {
   protected function index($setting) {
...
}
public function foo(){
...
}
```

Basically, I want to make an AJAX call to it from whatever page/route the module is on.
Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done in the same way you would for any module. For instance, if you'd added `foo()` to `/catalog/controller/module/cart.php` you would use

```
index.php?route=module/cart/foo
```

There's nothing special about the module controllers compared with any other accessible module

Comment: You are right,it works. I don't know what threw me off to start with. Must've been over-thinking it.Thanks a lot!